# Gradle Exec task not exiting

Tags: tomcat, gradle

I am new to Gradle and I am using a small task to start/stop local tomcat server.

My gradle task:

```
task startTomcat(type: Exec){
    workingDir ENV['CATALINA_HOME'] + '/bin'
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'catalina.bat'
    args 'start'
}
```

When I run this task, tomcat does start. But the task is not completing and keeps on waiting.
I have gone through [Exec documentation page](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) but could not get any clue.

Please help.

Comment: The task will complete when `cmd /c catalina.bat` exits. Maybe you have to pass the right arguments to `cmd` or the batch script, or edit the script to make it return early.

Comment: cmd /c opens in a separate window, that I don't mind. Another problem is that I should not change catalina.bat(Tomcat). Can I make use of execResult property and do a manual exit in the task ?

Comment: An `Exec` task will only complete once the process it started has exited. There is no way around this. Of course you could write your own exec-like task based on (say) Java's `ProcessBuilder` class, or perhaps use some Ant task that supports asynchronous execution of external processes.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the inputs. Shared the working task using ProcessBuilder.

Comment: This code is running `cmd start`, you should run gradle with `--info` to see what's the actual action executed, look for "Starting process 'command"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Peter for the input. Here is the solution that worked for me using `ProcessBuilder`:

```
/* Configuration for tomcat */
task catalinaConfig {
    ext.binDir = ENV['CATALINA_HOME'] + "\\bin"
}

task startTomcat << {   
    println "Tomcat path: " + catalinaConfig.binDir 
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(["cmd", "/c", "catalina.bat", "start"]);
    pb.directory(new File(catalinaConfig.binDir));

    println "Starting tomcat now ... "
    Process proc = pb.start();
    proc.waitFor();
    println "Tomcat is coming up now ... " + proc.exitValue()
}

task stopTomcat << {    
    println "Tomcat path: " + catalinaConfig.binDir 
    ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder(["cmd", "/c", "catalina.bat", "stop"]);
    pb1.directory(new File(catalinaConfig.binDir));

    println "Stopping tomcat now ... "
    Process proc1 = pb1.start();
    proc1.waitFor();
}
```

Comment: But that's no different in that it also waits for the process to exit. Looking at this again, I think the problem with your use of `Exec` is that you used both `commandLine` and `args`, which are either-or. Setting `commandLine` is the same as setting `executable` *and* setting `args`.

Comment: It only waited till "cmd /c catalina.bat start" was launched(or a timeout I suppose). The task completed as soon as command prompt opened. Do you mean to say proc.waitFor() should have waited till the exit of catalina.bat run?

Comment: I'm saying that your code does the same as the `Exec` task, namely to wait for the process to terminate (`proc1.waitFor()`). Hence if the `Exec` task behaved differently, then probably because you didn't configure it correctly (see my previous comment).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running on Windows, you've likely encountered this bug: [Process execution hangs on Windows if child processes are still alive](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3987). Unfortunately I don't have a simpler workaround to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

To immediately exit after the external process started I used:

```
task startServer(type:Exec) {
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","start.bat")
  pb.directory(new File("workingFolder"))
  pb.start();
}
```