# Gradle commandLine task doesn't exit

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I am trying to start a server with a Gradle task. I have it working, but Gradle hangs on the server starting without exiting. Looking around I see [workaround1](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/How-to-move-to-next-task-when-gradle-starts-a-new-command-window-td3406276.html) [workaround2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168742/gradle-exec-task-not-exiting) but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner implementation. It would seem like Gradle would have a cleaner implementation.

```
task startVertx(type:Exec) {

        workingDir 'build/classes/main'
        commandLine '../../../vertx/bin/vertx', 'run', 'Server'

        standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

        //extention method startVertex.output() for output
        ext.output = {
                return standardOutput.toString()
        }

}
```

This is what I have done, but as others suggest I may be thinking of the problem incorrectly

```
task startVertx << {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(["../../../vertx/bin/vertx",   "run", "Server"])
    pb.directory(new File("build/classes/main"))
    pb.start()
}

task launch(type: Exec, dependsOn: startVertx){

    commandLine 'firefox', 'http://localhost:8080'

    //store the output instead of printing to the console:
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    //extension method stopTomcat.output() can be used to obtain the output:
    ext.output = {
        return standardOutput.toString()
    }
}

task stopVertx(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'killall', 'java'
}
```

Comment: The same happens if you run that from the command line. Or ant. Or maven. I'm not sure the main way of running your app should be via a build system

Comment: I agree. There is an Application plugin for a reason, and it generates fancy startup scripts as well. http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: I was actually thinking it would be a way to test the interface? Run the app, run the tests. Is there a better approach?