# gradle Exec start tomcat: not exiting

Tags: gradle, exec, exit

I have looked at 
[Gradle Exec task not exiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168742/gradle-exec-task-not-exiting)
which does not use startup.bat

```
task startTomcat(type: Exec){
    workingDir '/path/tomcat/bin'
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'startup.bat'
}
```

The task starts tomcat, but never exit. I have to press CTRL+C.

If run "cmd /c startup.bat" outside gradle, it will start tomcat in another console and exit immediately.

Comment: I assume that the `startup.bat` process exits immediately, but not the surrounding `cmd` process. Did you try to use `commandLine 'startup.bat'`?

Comment: Yes. it tried. Grade was not able to find the startup.bat.

Comment: Are you sure that `startup.bat` is located in the `workingDir`? Or did you add it to the `PATH`? Did you try to specify the full path to the script?

Comment: commandLine 'startup.bat' will behave the same. The task exits only after the tomcat is stopped.