# Gradle task to start & stop a non-embedded tomcat container

Tags: tomcat, gradle

I have managed to create a `copyToLocalTomcat` task that copies my WAR file to my `TOMCAT_HOME` directory:

```
task copyToLocalTomcat(group: 'Deployment') {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from('app/build/libs') {
                include '*.war'
            }
            into "$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps"
        }
    }
}
```

I am now trying to create a gradle task that will run the `%TOMCAT_HOME%/bin/startup` script and one that runs the `%TOMCAT_HOME%/bin/shutdown` script.

I have read about the [Gradle Tomcat Plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin) but it seems that is for embedded applications. How can I do this for a non-embedded container?

---

Ideally I would like to be able to run:

```
gradlew --continue copyToLocalTomcat startTomcat endToEndTest stopTomcat
```

To run my end to end test suite without having to manually run the startup and shutdown scripts

Comment: I have since discovered a good solution in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168742/gradle-exec-task-not-exiting