# How to run a gradle task after bootRun has started up the Springboot app

Tags: java, spring, gradle, bootrun

I am trying to create a gradle task that will execute a postman collection against a running Spring Boot app. For this to happen the first part of the task has to be that the app is started using `gradle bootRun`. The problem is that this task never finishes as the server just keeps running.

How could I write this task in a way that will start up the Springboot app, run the postman collection and then stop the app?

```
tasks.register('runE2Etests') {
    group "E2E Tests"
    doLast {
        exec {
            commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'gradle bootRun'
        }
        exec {
            commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'newman run src/main/resources/manualTestData/example.postman_collection.json'
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote the task above but the task is stuck at `gradle bootRun` as that is a continuous task and because of this it never goes to the next part of it.

Comment: You can start the SpringBoot application process without waiting for it to complete using `ProcessBuilder` as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22196999/12092416. You will need to create another task to stop it.

Comment: tasks.register('startApp') {
 group "E2E Tests"
 doLast {
  exec {
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(['cmd', '/c', 'gradle bootRun'])
   Process process = pb.start()
   process.waitFor()
   println "Tomcat is coming up now ... " + process.exitValue()
  }
 }
}

I tried to use this but it does not work, it just get stuck at the loading stage